# Unsure if alias to combine apt-get update and apt-get upgrade is working correctly

Tags: apt, upgrade, alias, software-updates

Here are the aliases in question:

```
alias update='sudo apt-get update'
alias upgrade='sudo apt-get upgrade'
alias upgrate='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'
```

Here's the output when I run update:

```
[Wed Jul 08 20:47] gsw @ MacWoody:~ $ update
[sudo] password for gsw: 
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                              
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                      
Hit:4 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                             
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/screenfetch/ubuntu groovy InRelease          
Hit:6 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/screenfetch/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/screenfetch/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Here's the output when I run upgrade:

```
[Wed Jul 08 20:47] gsw @ MacWoody:~ $ upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Here's the output when I run upgrate, which should combine both processes.  It looks to me as if it's not doing the upgrade portion of the command and I'm not sure why:

```
[Wed Jul 08 20:48] gsw @ MacWoody:~ $ upgrate
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                             
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/screenfetch/ubuntu groovy InRelease          
Hit:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                      
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease              
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/screenfetch/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/screenfetch/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Based on the output of upgrate, it looks as if it’s only updating the repository but not going on to upgrade packages. Any help or information you can provide is appreciated, thank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&&` means the following command will only run if the previous one exited with `0`.

Seeing as `apt-get update` is producing errors, its return code will not be `0` - and therefore, `apt-get upgrade` is not executed.

Workaround:

```
alias upgrate='sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade'
```